# Twilio Media Stream and websocket server socketio python

Tags: python, server, socket.io, twilio, twilio-twiml

Does anybody know if the socketio library is compatible with Twilio media stream?

I have a sanic blueprint application and want to retrieve audio inside it. I build a websocket async server with socketio and attached the application to it.

I'm getting "31920 Stream - WebSocket - Handshake Error" which may suggest that socketio is a not compatible.

Comment: I can't see a reason that socketio wouldn't support connections with Twilio media streams. Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I just got a confirmation from Twilio Voice Support Team that SocketIO is not compatible with Streams and will not work.